# How to delete rows in a datagridview and at the same time updating the database in Access

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database, datagridview

I am developing an application in C # with access to a database created in MS Access 2007.

I have a WindowsForm to delete records from the database, but I'm only able to delete rows in the datagridview (except the first) and the database is not being updated.

I get this error when I try to delete a row:

> System.Data.OleDbException (0x80040E10): There was provided no value
>   to one or more required parameters.

Here is my code:

```
private void btn_remover_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Stock_Material.accdb"))
    {
        try
        {
            oleConn.Open();

            if (MessageBox.Show("Tem a certeza que pretende remover este registo(s)", " Confirmação", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
                   foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView_remover.SelectedRows)
                   {

                       int rowId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);

                       if (rowId > 0)
                       {
                           dataGridView_remover.Rows.RemoveAt(row.Index);
                           OleDbCommand delcmd = new OleDbCommand("Delete from product where id_Produto= " + rowId + "");
                           delcmd.Connection = oleConn;
                           delcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                       }
                   }
               }
               catch (Exception ex )
               {
                   MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
               }

               oleConn.Close();
           }
        }
```

How can I solve these problems:

- The database is not updated when i delete a record in the datagridview.
- Don't let me delete the first line in datagridview

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are connecting to the Access database in the projects folder.

By default the database will be copied to your bin folder every time you build the project, so your changes are overwritten.

To avoid this, put your database in the bin folder (debug or release) and make sure the database isn't copied.  You can do this by clicking on your database file in Visual Studio and set **Copy to Output Directory** to **Do not copy**